# error happened when bind cpp code with pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I try to bind code with pybind11 like this:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
    
namespace py = pybind11;
    
class PyTestArg {
public:
    PyTestArg(const std::string& vocab, const py::kwargs& kwargs) {
            // Constructor implementation
     }
};
    
PYBIND11_MODULE(python_example, m) {
    py::class_<PyTestArg>(m, "test").def(
     py::init<const std::string&, 
     const py::kwargs&>(),
     py::arg("vocab"), 
     py::arg("kwargs")
    );
}
```

However, this always produces the error below, even though I thought I have passed in the correct arguments:

```
In file included from src/main.cpp:1:
      /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:217:9: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'expected_num_args<pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::detail::is_new_style_constructor, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg>(sizeof...(Args), argument_loader<pybind11::detail::value_and_holder &, const std::string &, const pybind11::kwargs &>::args_pos >= 0, argument_loader<pybind11::detail::value_and_holder &, const std::string &, const pybind11::kwargs &>::has_kwargs)' "The number of argument annotations does not match the number of function arguments"
              static_assert(
              ^
      /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:101:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<(lambda at /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h:205:13), void, pybind11::detail::value_and_holder &, const std::string &, const pybind11::kwargs &, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::detail::is_new_style_constructor, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg>' requested here
              initialize(
              ^
      /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1568:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<(lambda at /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h:205:13), pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::detail::is_new_style_constructor, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, void>' requested here
              cpp_function cf(method_adaptor<type>(std::forward<Func>(f)),
                           ^
      /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h:203:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::class_<PyTestArg>::def<(lambda at /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/init.h:205:13), pybind11::detail::is_new_style_constructor, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg>' requested here
              cl.def(
                 ^
      /private/var/folders/j6/cd1wt3mn0xx0hjc9xc63qfqr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-u_92z2qj/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1606:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<const std::string &, const pybind11::kwargs &>::execute<pybind11::class_<PyTestArg>, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, 0>' requested here
              init.execute(*this, extra...);
                   ^
      src/main.cpp:115:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::class_<PyTestArg>::def<const std::string &, const pybind11::kwargs &, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg>' requested here
              .def(py::init<const std::string&, const py::kwargs&>(), py::arg("vocab") , py::arg("kwargs") );
```

What causes this error?

When I write the code like this, there is no error:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
    #include <pybind11/stl.h>
    
    namespace py = pybind11;
    
    class PyTestArg {
    public:
        PyTestArg(const std::string& vocab, const py::kwargs& kwargs) {
            // Constructor implementation
        }
    };
    
    PYBIND11_MODULE(python_example, m) {
        py::class_<PyTestArg>(m, "test")
            .def(py::init<const std::string&, const py::kwargs&>());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you haven't actually given them default values yet, try:

```
.def(py::init<const std::string&, const py::kwargs&>(), py::arg("vocab") = "");
```

Secondly you will notice I have missed out the `py::arg()` tag. This is because the documentation says it should not be included:
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#accepting-args-and-kwargs

Alternatively you could use: `py::kw_only()`
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#keyword-only-arguments